# Dual monitor DVI kvm

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors, connection-sharing, peripherals, kvm-switch

Setup 2 DVI LCDs, 1 USB keyboard, 1 USB mouse, regular one jack audio.

2 PCs.

I would like to share the peripherals/input devices between the two PCs but so far the dual DVI/USB/Audio KVM I found are super expensive ($200+) if you compare them to simpler 1 DVI head (few $ secondhand, sub $100 new).

What I was thinking is to buy two KVMs instead of one (I understand that I would then need to switch two buttons)

First one would be for peripherals + main LCB
Second one would be for the second LCB only.

Would this work? Am I missing something in my understanding of KVMs? I feel like I do cause I certainly don't understand why they cost THAT much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the expensive KVM will unplug the USB devices properly. You can't just let it be used with multiple devices, so it acts like a USB hub as well. You could therefore get away with the less expensive one, then plug a USB hub into the device, or into one computer at a time

Comment: So assuming I buy a decent KVM or a reg. hub for the USB devices would my idea of two "cheaper" KVM for each DVI port work you think?

Comment: It'd be a pain, but as long as you know which USB devices are attached to each, you should be fine. Just be warned, don't attach external HDDs with Write Caching